# Php web app and reply to email to call a function

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, confirmation-email

I'm developing a web app in php using codeignitor. I want to implement "reply to this email with approved in email body to update the app." feature.

Nowadays wen web apps send email for approvals, we can directly reply to email so the app will get updated once you send the reply. How does this feature implemented? I searched the web couldn't get any clues.

Comment: I know it's not a helpdesk. I Have just ask for some clues.

Comment: this is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12513390/is-it-possible-to-write-an-email-parser-in-php/12513563

Answer (score 1):

You can create a script polling the inbox of a specific email address and approving emails it got answer from. You would then need to set up cron jobs to run the script periodically.

Comment: In this case can we embed some hidden data in the email. For example. The record id we need to update etc.

Comment: why would you need that? usually email is a valide unique condition in auth systems, you can get the user id by querying for the email

Comment: Yes. We can get the user, but he might approve several records. So need an option to identify the correct record we need to update.

Comment: Those other records **must** be linked to the newly approved user one way or another

Comment: In most web apps, I have noticed that the reply email add is very lengthy and have hex characters. So how these emails routed to one inbox?

Comment: That's a question more suited for ServerFault since it will prolly be a mailserver specific setup